# Merge two specific columns from a line in C language

Tags: c, string, merge, line, multiple-columns

I want to merge two specific columns from a line in C language. The line is like "hello world  hello world". It consists of some words and some white space. The below is my code. In this function, c1 and c2 represent the number of the column, and array key is mergeed string. But it's not good to run.

```
char *LinetoKey(char *line, int c1, int c2, char key[COLSIZE]){
    char *col2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    while (*line != '\0' && isspace(*line) )
        line++;
    while(*line != '\0' && c1 != 0){
        if(isspace(*line)){
            while(*line != '\0' && isspace(*line))
                line++;
            c1--;
            c2--;
        }else
            line++;
    }
    while (*line != '\0' && *line != '\n' && (isspace(*line)==0))
        *key++ = *line++;
    *key = '\0';
    while(*line != '\0' && c2 != 0){
        if(isspace(*line)){
            while(*line != '\0' && isspace(*line))
                line++;
            c2--;
        }else
            line++;
    }
    while (*line != '\0' && *line != '\n' && isspace(*line)==0)
        *col2++ = *line++;
    *col2 = '\0';
    strcat(key,col2);
    return key;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to write a own function that splits up your line into single tokens(columns) by simply returning an string pointer within line and a length. Then use this function in your LinetoKey implementation. This reduces the complexity of the code. Test both functions separately and combined.

Comment: With `(char *)malloc(sizeof(char));` you are only allocating memory for a _single character_ - so you when you write more than one character to `col2` you will be writing to unallocated memory.

Comment: _"The line is like "hello world hello world""_ What's the expected output?

Comment: @ZDF: If `c1` is `0` and `c3` is `3` I presume the expected output would be `"helloworld"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution using `strtok()`. It can handle an arbitrary number of columns (increase the size of `buf` if necessary), and will still work if the order of the columns is reversed (i.e. `c1` > `c2`). The function returns `1` on success (tokens successfully merged), `0` otherwise.

Note that `strtok()` modifies its argument - so I have copied `input` to a temporary buffer, `char buf[64]`.

```
/*
 * Merge space-separated 'tokens' in a string.
 * Columns are zero-indexed.
 *
 * Return: 1 on success, 0 on failure
 */
int merge_cols(char *input, int c1, int c2, char *dest) {
    char buf[64];
    int col = 0;
    char *tok = NULL, *first = NULL, *second = NULL, *tmp = NULL;

    if (c1 == c2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Columns can not be the same !");
        return 0;
    }

    if (strlen(input) > sizeof(buf) - 1) return 0;

    /*
     * strtok() is _destructive_, so copy the input to
     * a buffer.
     */
    strcpy(buf, input);

    tok = strtok(buf, " ");
    while (tok) {
        if (col == c1 || col == c2) {
            if (!first)
                first = tok;
            else if (first && !second)
                second = tok;
        }
        if (first && second) break;
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
        col++;
    }
    // In case order of columns is swapped ...
    if (c1 > c2) {
        tmp = second;
        second = first;
        first = tmp;
    }
    if (first) strcpy(dest, first);
    if (second) strcat(dest, second);

    return first && second;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
char *input = "one two three four five six seven eight";
char dest[128];

// The columns can be reversed ...
int merged = merge_cols(input, 7, 1, dest);
if (merged)
    puts(dest);
```

Note also that it is very easy to use different delimiters when using `strtok()` - so if you wanted to use comma- or tab-separated input instead of spaces, you just change the second argument when calling it.

Comment: Instead of passing `c1` and `c2`, why not pass an array containing `c1, c2`? If you are only concerned with 2 columns, then it doesn't matter, but if the number of columns you are interested in may vary, then passing an array, and the number of elements in that array would allow you to loop over the array making the column number comparisons without hardcoding tests for only 2.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Here is an attempt at that: [link](http://codepad.org/AOjspirA). (Haven't posted here because it seems the OP wants something more specific.)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you're trying to do. If what David Collins suggested is what you're looking for - word concatenation by word index - here's a starting point ([demo](https://ideone.com/0uKTLe)):

- Your function must **minimize the number of string traversals**. To help this, the code below is using `char**` instead of `char*` (sort of "char streams").
- The function must be able to **count the number of characters the result will have**, prior to actual concatenation, in order to be able to allocate the destination string on free store. If `catwords` is called with null destination, it only counts the length of the result string.

Regarding the actual implementation, you will have to traverse the string **word by word** and decide whether to **copy** or **skip** the word. See the code below for the following functions:

- `nextword` - skips white-spaces until it finds a non-white-space character.
- `copyword` - copies the current word if destination is valid or skips it if not. It returns the number of copied/skipped characters.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void nextword( const char** ps )
{
  while ( **ps && isspace( **ps ) )
    ++*ps;
}

int copyword( char** const pd, const char** ps )
{
  // remember the starting point
  const char* b = *ps;

  // actual copy
  if ( pd && *pd ) while ( **ps && !isspace( **ps ) )
    *( *pd )++ = *( *ps )++;

  // skip the word (no destination)
  else while ( **ps && !isspace( **ps ) )
    ( *ps )++;

  // return the length
  return *ps - b;
}

int catwords( char* d, const char* s, const int* c )
{
  int len = 0;
  int iw = 0;
  int ic = 0;
  const char** ps = &s;
  char** pd = &d;

  for ( nextword( ps ); **ps && c[ ic ] > -1; nextword( ps ), ++iw )
    if ( iw == c[ ic ] )
    {
      len += copyword( pd, ps );
      ++ic;
    }
    else
    {
      copyword( 0, ps ); // just skip the current word
    }

  if ( d )
    **pd = '\0';

  return len;
}

int main()
{
  // static buffer test
  {
    char d[ 1024 ];
    int t[] = { 0, 3, -1 };
    catwords( d, "Hello world. Hello world!", t );
    puts( d );
  }

  // dynamic buffer test
  {
    const char* s = "The greatness of a man is not in how much wealth he acquires, but in his integrity and his ability to affect those around him positively.";
    int t[] = { 1, 5, 16, -1 };
    int dstcharcount = catwords( 0, s, t ) + 1;
    char* d = (char*)malloc( dstcharcount * sizeof( char ) );
    catwords( d, s, t );
    puts( d );
    free( d );
  }

  return 0;
}
```